# How to check if a string is empty in C (nothing has worked so far)

Tags: c

I have to make a code that checks to see whether the Student 1's first name was blank and if it was then ask the user to input a name. However, when I use this code it doesn't display that message. When I press enter the cursor just goes to the next line until I actually type something in. I've tried this with strcmp too and nothing works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
{

char charStudent1FirstName[50] = "";

printf("Please enter Student 1's First name: ");
scanf("%s", &charStudent1FirstName);

if (charStudent1FirstName[0] == '\0')
   {
       printf("Please input Student 1's first name again: ");
       scanf("%s", &charStudent1FirstName);
   }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Idiomatic way of checking for an empty string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609662/idiomatic-way-of-checking-for-an-empty-string-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: Note that you want `charStudent1FirstName`, not `&charStudent1FirstName` (both times). Did your compiler not warn you of that?

Comment: @Barnabus That's not the OP's actual problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I changed:

1. Use `fgets` instead of `scanf`. This means you will actually see the blank line if that's all that's entered.
2. Trim the newline from the `fgets` result.
3. Use `charStudent1FirstName` instead of `&charStudent1FirstName`. You want to pass a `char*`, not a `char**`. If your compiler doesn't warn you about this, consider using a different compiler or changing your compilation settings.
4. Use a loop so the user is prompted to enter a name as many times as necessary until one is entered.

Complete working code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char charStudent1FirstName[50] = "";

    while (charStudent1FirstName[0] == 0) {
        printf("Please input Student 1's first name: ");
        fgets(charStudent1FirstName, 50, stdin);
        charStudent1FirstName[strcspn(charStudent1FirstName, "\n")] = 0;
    }

    printf("First name: %s\n", charStudent1FirstName);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing wrong with the way that you're checking for the empty string.  Your issue is that you're using [`scanf`, which is notoriously hard to use](http://www.c-faq.com/stdio/scanfprobs.html). `scanf` handles whitespace probably not in the way you expect: you want *line*-based input, but `scanf` reads a *stream of tokens*. `scanf` does not care about newlines, so in your case, it won't read anything until you type in non-whitespace and therefore will not retrieve an empty string.

Instead, you should read an entire line using `fgets` (or POSIX `getline` if available) and then parse that line (if necessary) with `sscanf`. (Note that `fgets` can leave a newline at the end of the string, so you must strip that off.)

---

Perhaps beating a dead horse, your usage of `scanf` is also *unsafe* because you do not limit the amount of data that it can write to `charStudent1FirstName`, and consequently a user could easily overflow the destination buffer.  While it's possible to jump through some hoops to use `scanf` safely when reading strings, using `fgets`/`getline` would avoid these problems. (Additionally, using `fgets`/`getline` would make it more obvious that you should be passing `charStudent1FirstName` as an argument, not `&charStudent1FirstName`.)